# Error transferring bitcoins to another wallet

Tags: withdrawal, money-transfer

I'm a beginner in the bitcoin context.
I opened an account online with Bitpanda and I have a wallet on my computer with Bitcoin core.
I bought some bitcoins for testing and I want to move them into my Bitcoin core wallet.
But everytime that I try the transfer, bitpanda says me that my internal wallet does not have enough bitcoin but I did not specified any amount of bitcoins to transfer.

From what this may depend?

Answer (score 3):

This is unrelated to Bitcoin itself. [Bitpanda has a minimum withdrawal amount](https://www.bitpanda.com/en/limits), and it seems that you do not have at least that amount to withdraw. The amount seems to be the equivalent of 100 USD (specifically, it is 0.002167 BTC at time of writing).

If you do in fact have more funds in your account than that amount, I would advise [contacting Bitpanda for support](https://support.bitpanda.com/hc/en-us/requests/new).